# Accessibility in WP7 (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, accessibility

Does anyone have any resources on how to make Silverlight WP7 apps more accessible for the visually impaired?

I have some apps in SL4 to be ported over WP7 that are intentionally designed to include accessibility components, but it seems even the simplest thing like `Windows.SystemColors` don't work in WP7 (every system color just shows up as black, regardless of the theme).

Would appreciate anything you've got - links, official word from big M, personal experience, a looking glass into the future...

Answer (score 1):

The last bit of information I saw on accessibility on WP7 was in the Answers forums (http://answers.microsoft.com) in which on of the support engineers mentioned that accessibility work for WP7 was still underway.

Comment: Joel, I've searched hi and low for that thread, but can't find it. Do you have a link?

Comment: It may not be there any more. Microsoft recently replaced their older Answers platform with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are currently no accessibility features in WP7 that are targeted towards visually impaired users. While there are some APIs relating to accessibility (AutomationPeer, et al) they won't get picked up by the O/S. At this point, it's pretty pointless to worry about WP7 accessibility since most visually impaired users will simply not own a WP7.

Comment: Justin, the definition of "visually impaired" usually begins with  the minor disability of color blindness, which affects a larger number of people (especially men) than you may think. I've got two color blind friends, both of whom own a WP7.